# Check SQL SYS_REFCURSOR without changing the cursor position

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, cursor

I have a requirement to check if a cursor was able to get some rows from table A. If yes, then do nothing else pull rows from table B.
Currently there are two stored procedures for now.
I am trying to do this in one stored procedure.
I tried using %ROWCOUNT but it doesn't work(because it will return 0) without changing the location of the cursor.
The issue is that my output is the cursor so I don't want to make any changes to.
If I do a fetch, then it shows error also that the return type has changed.
Any idea how to do this, like even if create a copy the cursor so that the fetch and row count could be done on the copy instead of the output cursor.
Pseudo Example

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "proc"
(
    output OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
)
.
BEGIN
.
.
OPEN output for select * from A
END

BEGIN
//check if output was empty then
OPEN output for select * from B

.
.
END
```

Update:
I did as suggested

```
....
BEGIN
...
OPEN output for 
  with 
    A as (select ...),
   ,B as (select ...),
   ,C as (select ...),
   ,D as (select ...)
  select * from A
   union 
  select * from B where not exists(select null from A)
   union 
  select * from C where not exists(select null from B)
   union 
  select * from D where not exists(select null from C)
END;
```

Since I know for sure that either one these tables will have data, I also tried the below

```
....
BEGIN
...
OPEN output for 
  with 
    A as (select ...)
   ,B as (select ...)
   ,C as (select ...),
   ,D as (select ...)
  select * from A
   union 
  select * from B
   union 
  select * from C
   union 
  select * from D 
END;
```

But it gives me error now that
Error(64,7): PL/SQL: ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns
The table structure foe these 4 is diff. So they might return diff columns.
Would join make sense if 3 out of 4 are empty?

Comment: Create a small code that simulates your problem. Try to create it here... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18 Because it is with code you need help not with story...

Comment: updated with a pseudo code.

Comment: Do you want to do it in the same procedure (in your example `proc`)?

Comment: Yes in the same proc

Comment: But you have asked the same question yesterday ? What is wrong with the yesterday answer ?? Add that problem to this question...

Comment: Yesterday was to check null or non null. Empty and null isn't the same. SO that answer doesn't suffice empty response. I think thats why the yesterday's solution didnt work when I used it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to implement your requirement in the same cursor, because it will use the same point-in-time read consistency: in your approach second `open` opens cursor for a different time than your first cursor and really data in A and B can change already.

This approach is better:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "proc"( output OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,...)
....
BEGIN
...
OPEN output for 
  with 
    A as (select ...)
   ,B as (select ...)
  select * from A
   union all
  select * from B where not exists(select null from A)
END;
```

Another possible solution is to create pipelined table instead, like:

```
create or replace function ... return {collection type} PIPELINED as
...flag boolean := true;
begin
....
  for i in (select * from A) loop
    flag:=false;
    pipe row(...)
  end loop;
  if flag then
    for i in (select * from B) loop
      flag:=false;
      pipe row(...)
    end loop;
  end if;
end;
/
```

But as you can see both query are opened at different time too.

Comment: @SonaliGupta `union` parts should return the same number of columns with the same data types, so you just need to add `null`s columns to the parts where you have no enough columns

Comment: And I wonder how do you process ref cursor in case of different number of columns? do you ignore some of them?

Comment: The current practice is to take one stored proc response, run java code. Write all the logic in Java and then if needed call the second stored proc. Hence diff responses dont make a diff as it is handle in Java.

Comment: The easiest way would be to follow the same way, I just wanted to see if instead of making two DB calls this could be done in one.

Comment: @SonaliGupta strictly speaking you can return both ref cursors from the same one procedure: usual ref cursors (without `for update` clause) are just "links", they do nothing until you start fetching them.

Comment: Wow, that might actually work. I need to see how multiple cursor return works because I am a noob in this but for these 4 tables I can simply return 4 cursors, I suppose. Thanks.